# A series that came up in the context of solving a reccurence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I needed to solve a recurrence relation and used the recursion tree method. I simplified the series that the tree gave me and eventually got to a point where I needed to evaluate $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{-k}{2^k}$. I'm not proficient with series yet, and I don't know how to evaluate this series. I tried arriving at something that looks like a geometric series but to no avail. How to evaluate this series? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? (In the case of $p=1/2$ specifically.) [Proof for Mean of Geometric Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291136/proof-for-mean-of-geometric-distribution) See also the answers here: [Deriving the mean of the Geometric Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310816/deriving-the-mean-of-the-geometric-distribution)

Comment: Yes, thanks!!!!

Comment: more generally since $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$ you can obtain sums $\sum p(k) x^k$ where $p$is polynomial by successive derivations or integrations. Convergence is not an issue with geometric series. I.e. here $\sum \frac {-k}{2^k}=-\frac 12\sum k\left(\frac 12\right)^{k-1}$